# How to nest 2 different formulas in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to combine these 2 formulas in one cell. I'm trying to get 2 different dates in one cell. To show in the end (e.g. 2/15/2024 / 2/24/2024.

My 2 formulas

```
=($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)+14

=($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)+23
```

Comment: You need concatenation, but you also might need to format your dates as strings (of the "YYYY/MM/DD" (or another) format, because basic formatting will show your dates are numbers, which will be useless.

Answer (score 3):

Using `TEXTJOIN()` will be suffice here, as well one don't need two formulas, you can make it into one as compact by the use of `+{14,23}`:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(" / ",1,TEXT((C1-DAY(C1)+1)+{14,23},"m/d/e"))
```

---

Also instead of using a `slash` in between as a delimiter, it will look good in using a `hyphen` however it depends on ones choice:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",1,TEXT((C1-DAY(C1)+1)+{14,23},"m/d/e"))
```

---

**Note:** In date formatting `e` has been used for years `y` which is universal.

---

**Added Infos:** When used comma in between `{14,23}` it returns columns wise while when used `{14;23}` it returns row wise, both packed within `TEXTJOIN()` to return a delimited value as shown above:

[image]

---

• **ROW Wise**

```
=TEXT((C1-DAY(C1)+1)+{14;23},"m/d/e")
```

---

• **COLUMN Wise**

```
=TEXT((C1-DAY(C1)+1)+{14,23},"m/d/e")
```

---

Comment: You only need to use "e" once in the format code.

Comment: @MGonet perfect Sir!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you that worked wonders. What If I wanted to add a conditional formatting to that cell. When I used 1 date I've used =AND($L$13>0,$L$13<TODAY()) So it would give me back a color of Red. and for Orange I would use =AND($L$13-TODAY()>=0,$L$13-TODAY()<=3).    How would I be able to this for 2 dates in one cell.

Comment: @DannyZambrano as far I know this is not possible. You cannot have two colors for two conditions in one cell. Having said that, the best practice when working with dates is to avoid using concatenating cells, Since dates and times are stored as numbers and fractions of day, so it wont be very helpful and will make things further complicated.

Answer (score 2):

[Mayukh's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1827922/348859) is a good one but there is another that may be more approachable for less experienced Excel users. It's also a viable option for people using versions of Excel that do not offer the `TEXTJOIN()` function.

The operator `&` can be used to concatenate text. For instance, the formula `="A" & "B"` will result in the cell value `AB`. We can do the same thing with your formula. We want  `/`  in between the two dates so we do this:

```
=($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)+14 & " / " & ($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)+23
```

[image]

That doesn't look right, though, because Excel treats all dates as numbers. We can use `TEXT()` to dictate a format for Excel to use instead of the default.

```
=TEXT(($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)+14,"m/d/yyyy") & " / " & TEXT(($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)+23,"m/d/yyyy")
```

[image]

---

This is not the best answer for those with access to the latest versions of Excel. It's more difficult to maintain, it has the same formula twice (`($C$1-DAY($C$1)+1)`), and it's just clunkier.